# How to make drop-down menu within Oracle Application Express?

Tags: oracle, database-design, user-interface, oracle-apex

I would really appreciate if anybody could shed some light on this, as search engine results have been singularly unhelpful so far.

I am attempting to build a GUI for an oracle database through Application Express. There tend to be tricks of how to set up drop down menus through the Graphical User Interface of the product that one uses (for instance I would know how to do this in a product like Microsoft Access).

For instance I have this form

[image: Oracle Application Express form]

The foreign key for Business (FK_BUSINESS_ID) is just an integer - not terribly user friendly! If it could be a drop down list of business names (BUSINESS.NAME), it would be great. Hiding the business primary key (BUSINESS_ID) would make it look nicer, but isn't altogether relevant.

I have found the source controls for the element in question.

[image: form controls Oracle Application Express]

What sort of SQL (or even PL/SQL) could be used to both display this data from the other table, and return the selected foreign key selected by the user when the form is sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

1. Open up the item, and change the type to **Select List**
2. For **List of Values Definition**, enter `select BUSINESS.NAME, FK_BUSINESS_ID from [TABLE]`

#### Explanation

Select list shows display values to the user and returns the corresponding ID. Your source can remain the same as before.

Comment: I can't find the **Select list**